# Windows Authentication for ASP.NET Core with React.js project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

So, i have created a ASP.NET Core with React.js project from a visual studio template. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6RII.png)

The problem is, that i can't make windows authentication work. What I have added to my Program.cs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ8OU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTNnO.png)

I have also changed my launchsettings to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egf19.png)

When I try to call `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` it is always null.

When I re-checked the authentication types in the template I noticed, that there is no option for windows authentication:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1hvZ.png)

Do I need to use a different template to make windows authentication work?
Thanks in advance!

(I have tried a few other things in the program.cs and also tried creating a web.config, but nothing seems to work)

Comment: [Does the answer useful to you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75314914)